# Changing a context menu with Javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to modify the context menu for a right click on a specific item (a `tr`) to display some custom navigation options instead of the standard content. So far, I've found two ways of doing this: either bind some new behavior to the `contextmenu` event, and create a new div/dropdown menu based on the location of the event, (i.e. create my own context menu from scratch), or else use a plugin like [this jQuery plugin](https://github.com/joewalnes/jquery-simple-context-menu/blob/master/README.md) that will do the exact same thing for me.

What I'm wondering is if there is a way to use the skeleton of the default context menu, and just add some `<a>`s or `div`s that are bound to the events I want to trigger in place of what's already there. Is there a way of modifying the existing context menu, rather than dumping it and building my own either from scratch or with a plugin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way of modifying the existing context menu, rather than dumping it and building my own either from scratch or with a plugin?

**No**, sorry, the browsers don't expose that functionality.

Comment: Damn. Not the answer I was hoping for.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to modify an existing context menu - the question is only where and when.
This is part of [HTML5 specification](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/interactive-elements.html#context-menus) and current version of Firefox supports it.

```
<menu type="context" id="myVeryOwnMenu">
    <menuitem 
        label="Caption for your item" 
        onclick="veryObtrusiveEventHandler()" 
        icon="/path/to/your/icon.gif">
    </menuitem>
</menu>
```

...and even nesting is supported.

It seems that Chrome, IE and other leading browsers decide to be not interested about this HTML5 feature. Time will tell.

See http://davidwalsh.name/html5-context-menu for FF demo.

Comment: This has since been removed from HTML5, and is only still supported in Firefox. It is considered obsolete and it is inadvisable to use.